# Java regex returns full string instead of capture

Tags: java, regex

Java Code:

```
String imagesArrayResponse = xmlNode.getChildText("files");
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("path\":\"([^\"]*)").matcher(imagesArrayResponse);

while (m.find()) {
    String path = m.group(0);
}
```

String:

```
[{"path":"upload\/files\/56727570aaa08922_0.png","dir":"files","name":"56727570aaa08922_0","original_name":"56727570aaa08922_0.png"}{"path":"upload\/files\/56727570aaa08922_0.png","dir":"files","name":"56727570aaa08922_0","original_name":"56727570aaa08922_0.png"}{"path":"upload\/files\/56727570aaa08922_0.png","dir":"files","name":"56727570aaa08922_0","original_name":"56727570aaa08922_0.png"}{"path":"upload\/files\/56727570aaa08922_0.png","dir":"files","name":"56727570aaa08922_0","original_name":"56727570aaa08922_0.png"}]
```

m.group returns

```
path":"upload\/files\/56727570aaa08922_0.png"
```

instead of captured value of path. Where I am wrong?

Comment: `path = m.group(1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation of `group( int index )` method

When called with 0, it returns the entire string. Group 1 is the first.

To avoid such a trap, you should use named group with syntax :
`"path\":\"(?<mynamegroup>[^\"]*)"`

[javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)):

> Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group().

Answer (score 1):

m.group(1) will give you the Match. If there are more than one matchset (), it will be m.group(2), m.group(3),...

Answer (score 0):

By convention, AFAIK in regex engines the 0th group is always the whole matched string. Nested groups start at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the grouping options in [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)).

```
 Matcher m = 
   Pattern.compile(
    //<-     (0)     ->  that's group(0)
    //          <-(1)->  that's group(1)
     "path\":\"([^\"]*)").matcher(imagesArrayResponse);
```

Change your code to

```
while (m.find()) {
  String path = m.group(1);
}
```

And you should be okay. This is also worth checking out: [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group)